# aChart Engine and NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, achartengine

I'm trying to use aChart Engine in my project but I always get this annoying exception:

```
06-09 21:47:59.045: E/AndroidRuntime(19635): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 21:47:59.045: E/AndroidRuntime(19635): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 21:47:59.045: E/AndroidRuntime(19635):    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:739)
06-09 21:47:59.045: E/AndroidRuntime(19635):    at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:91)
06-09 21:47:59.045: E/AndroidRuntime(19635):    at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:176)
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Try to be more specific about what you did/didn't do, if possible pst some code (how and where did you link the aChart Engine in) - where you got your information how to use it ... Everybody here wants to help - but helping needs time, so its your responsibility as the one who poses the question that someone who wants to answer has all the information.

Comment: Can you show what are u trying to do?